# modelmapper-jooq and handling 'null' fields

Tags: java, jooq, modelmapper

I'm using modelmapper-jooq to map jOOQ records to custom pojos. Let's assume I have table like

```html
  | name | second_name | surname
----------------------------
1 | Mary | Jane        | McLeod
----------------------------
2 | John | Henry       | Newman
----------------------------
3 | Paul |             | Signac
----------------------------
4 | Anna |             | Pavlova
```

so the second_name can be `null`. My Person POJO looks like:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private String surname;
    // assume getters and setters
}
```

When I map `Result<Record>` into `Collection<Person>`, every element in this collection has secondName equal `null`. When I map only first two rows, everything is OK. How to handle it properly, so the secondName field is `null` only when corresponding field in database is `null`? I've checked that fields in Record instances have proper values. I configure modelmapper in this way:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().addValueReader(new RecordValueReader());
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);
```

Also I'm doing mapping like:

```
//...
private final Type collectionPersonType = new TypeToken<Collection<Person>>() {}.getType();
//...
Result<Record> result = query.fetch();
return modelMapper.map(result, collectionPersonType);
```